# canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG) is not working in android 9

Tags: android

In old android versions method is :: canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG)
But in new android 9 version method is :: "canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG)" 
it is not working in this new version.

Please help me to get the alternate method which suits this method.

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

It was deprecated in android 9,you can use `canvas.save()` instead